# A simple compound interest problem

Tags: word-problem

Here is a simple interest word problem that I apparently got it wrong. The problem is this:

> Isabel borrowed $8000$ dollars from a bank. If the interest is compounded $15$ percent monthly. How much money wil she owe after $6$ years if shee didn't make any payments?

My logic is this:
Suppose that the first month had passed, I will pay $8000(1.15)$. Then, the second month has passed and I will have to pay $8000(1.15)^2$. This paddern will continue until the 6 years has passed. Since there are $12$ months in a year, there will be $6*12=72$ months. Therefore, my solution is $8000(1.15)^72=187643918$.
However, the solution is $19567.36$, which in my oppinion, is wrong. The reason for this is the $15$ percent is compounded monthly, which means that every month, the bank will charge $15$ percent more than the previous month. Notice that they didn't say "15% interest anually compounded monthly" - if they did, then I would agree with their solution.

So, is my logic correct? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Notice that they didn't say "15% interest anually compounded monthly"

No, but when taking up a loan in a bank, that's exactly how the interest usually works. I would always expect, unless otherwise specified, that a bank's interest percentages are yearly, regardless of when it's compounded.

In much the same way that problem authors may sometimes assume people know how a standard deck of cards look (52 cards, four suits, etc.), this problem author assumed you knew how banks phrase their deals.

Comment: thanks, but in every compounding problems, they always tell me that the rate is $x$ percent per period. Anyway, thanks for your hep.

Comment: This is specifically a convention for loans. If I lend you money for tomorrow at a rate of 15%, that really means (15/366)%. (Or divided by 365 or 360 or something else depending on what the small print says, really).